# How to add php variable at the end of a link

Tags: php, html, variables, printing, echo

I have a noobish question (this is my first time coding in php) Basically, the script opens a button that opens a link, what im trying to do is use a variable to assign text in the form of a variable at the end of the link, i cant seem to do it, i tried to add the variable at the end of the script where the link is located, but the text simply shows on the page and nothing happens when you press the button, how do i do this?

```
while ( $offer = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $getcompleted = "SELECT * FROM `completed` WHERE offer_id='".$offer['id']."' AND user_id='".$ui['id']."'";
        $completed = mysql_query($getcompleted) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($completed)>0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $getpending = "SELECT * FROM `pending` WHERE offer_id='".$offer['id']."' AND user_id='".$ui['id']."'";
            $pending = mysql_query($getpending) or die(mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($pending)==0) {
                $getvisited = "SELECT * FROM visited WHERE offer_id='".$offer['id']."' AND user_id='".$ui['id']."'";
                $visited = mysql_query($getvisited) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($visited)==0) {
                    $button = "Open offer";
                } else {
                    $button = "Submit offer";
                }
                $link = "<form method=POST><input type=hidden name=action value=complete><input type=hidden name=oid value='".$offer['id']."'><input type=submit value='".$button."'></form>";
            } else {
                $pend=mysql_fetch_array($pending);
                if ($pend['status']==1) { $link = "<font color=yellow>Pending</font>"; }
                if ($pend['status']==2) { $link = "<font color=red>Denied</font>"; }
            }
            print "
            <tr>
            <td>".htmlentities($offer['name'])."</td>
            <td>".$offer['info']."</td>
            <td>".htmlentities($offer['country'])."</td>
            <td>".htmlentities($offer['reward'])."</td>
            <td>".$link."</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble following what it is specifically you're trying to insert and where.

Comment: Which part of the `if` are you talking about? When `mysql_num_rws($pending)` is not 0, you're just putting text into `$link`, not a form.

Comment: Im trying to put a variable (not shown in this code) at the end of the $link variable im trying to make it so when you click the Open Offer Button, the $userid variable will be added at the end of the $link variable. ANy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which $link variable are we talking about?

Inside this IF
    if (mysql_num_rows($pending)==0) {
or `else`

Why can't you just add the user id manually on that "link"?

Nothing happen when you press the button? The receiving post-php-script might be the problem.

Comment: this is the link variable  $link = "<form method=POST><input type=hidden name=action value=complete><input type=hidden name=oid value='".$offer['id']."'><input type=submit value='".$button."'></form>";, im REALLY noobish and i dont understand how to add the user id manually.